# Laravel 4, Controllers, and the Root URI

Tags: php, laravel

When I do this:

```
Route::controller('/', 'MyPackage\\Controllers\\HomeController');
```

The controller hijacks all routes in the application.  How do I do this so it only captures the root URI?

Comment: I believe the actual answer would be to put `Route::controller('/', 'MyPackage\\Controllers\\HomeController');` on the bottom of your Routes file.  Why your other method works, I'm not too sure.  Hopefully someone can chime in about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all has to do w/ the sequence of route declarations.

Make sure the route is last in your `workbench/vendor/package/src/routes.php` file:

```
Route::controller('foobar', 'MyPackage\\Controllers\\FoobarController');
Route::controller('/', 'MyPackage\\Controllers\\HomeController'); // this is last
```

Make sure the provider is last in your `app/config/app.php` file:

```
'Foobar\Provider',
'Mypackage\Provider', // this is last
```

You just want to make sure the route to the root is the last route considered by Laravel, when using it for a controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of creating RESTful controllers in Laravel for your root URI:

```
Route::controller('', 'MyPackage\\Controllers\\HomeController');
```

**Note that this answer is shown in an edit in OP, made by [@swt83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96295/swt83) himself.**